# Fix a menu problem in bootstrap 4 avoiding that each sub-dropdown-menu will overlap each other

Tags: html, css

This is pretty much what I would like to obtain:

[image]

I will explain my problem in this **codepen**:

[CodeLink](https://codepen.io/orso081980/pen/YJNVGp)

```css
/** Main Nav **/
#main-nav{
 margin:0 auto;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#main-nav .container-fluid{
 max-width:1366px;
 /**overflow:hidden;**/
 /*margin-top:5px;
 margin-top:5px;*/
}

#logo-container{
 text-align:center;
}

#menu-container{
 padding:0;
}

#menu-container ul {
 padding-left: 0px;
 /*display: inline;
 list-style: none;*/
}

.btn {
 color: #000;
 background-color: #FFF;
 border-color: #FFF;
 font-family: 'Daxline Medium';
 font-size: 1.1rem;
 border-bottom: 2px solid transparent!important;
}

.btn.dropdown-toggle.no-after::after {
 content: " " !important;
 border: 0 !important;
 margin-top: 23px;
 margin-left: 0.5em !important;
}

.btn:hover{
 color: #000;
 background-color: #FFF;
 border-color: #FFF;
 /*font-family: 'Daxline Bold';*/
 font-weight: bold;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #e41a2e!important;
 border-radius: 0px;
 /*letter-spacing: 0px;*/
}

.btn:focus{
 outline:none !important;
 box-shadow: none !important;
 font-family: 'Daxline Bold';
 border-bottom: 2px solid #e41a2e;
 border-radius:0px;
}

.dropdown-menu{
 top:-2px !important;
 border: none !important;
 border-radius: 0 !important;
 color: black;
 /*display: block!important;*/
 /*box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px #767676;*/
}

.dropdown-toggle::after{
 font-family: FontAwesome;
 content: "\f106" !important;
 border:0 !important;
 color:#818181;
 font-size: 1.4rem;
 vertical-align:unset !important;
 margin-left:0.5em !important;
}

.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
 display: block;
 /*margin-top: 50px;*/
}

.dropdown-menu > .sub-dropdown-menu {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0%;
 left: 100%;
 z-index: 1000;
 display: none; 
 float: left;
 min-width: 10rem;
 padding: .5rem 0;
 margin: .125rem 0 0;
 font-size: 1rem;
 color: #212529;
 text-align: left;
 list-style: none;
 background-color: #fff;
 background-clip: padding-box;
 /*border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);*/
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
 /*background: background: #F9F7F5;*/
 /*position: relative;*/
}

.dropdown-item:hover + .sub-dropdown-menu {
 display: block;
}
.sub-dropdown-menu:hover {
 display: block;
}
#menu-container ul li{
 display: inline;
}

.dropdown{
 width:fit-content;
 margin: 0 25px;
}

#phone-container-mobi{
 display:none;
}

#search-container-mobi{
 display:none;
}

#menu-container-mobi{
 display:none;
}

#featured-wrapper-mobi{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="menu-container" class="col-sm-9">
     <ul class="main-menu">
      <li class="dropdown show">
       <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">About</a>
    
       <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-dropdown-menu">
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 1</a></li>
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-dropdown-menu">
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 3</a></li>
         <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 4</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown show">
       <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Programs</a>
    
       <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 2</a>
       </div>
      </li>
    
      <li class="dropdown show">
       <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Locations</a>
    
       <div class="dropdown-menu" >
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 2</a>
       </div>
      </li>
    
      <li class="dropdown show">
       <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Admissions</a>
    
       <div class="dropdown-menu" >
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 2</a>
       </div>
      </li>
    
      <li class="dropdown show">
       <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Employment Services</a>
    
       <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Page 2</a>
       </div>
      </li>
    
      <li class="dropdown show">
       <a class="btn dropdown-toggle no-after" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Blog</a>
    
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Here as you can notice my menu doesn't work like I wish.

Each menu item (li) of the main navigation list (ul) has a drop-down menu and every drop-down menu has a sub-drop-down menu.

Now my problem is that on hover (css) I would like to open another sub-drop-down-menu on the right of my drop-down menu (li) that will match the high of his parent.

I use the position:absolute property to position them, but that is not working for some reason so every sub-drop-down-menu will overlap each other.

Is there something wrong with my markup (HTML) or should I fix my css? And how? Since I've already put them in an absolute positions connected with their parents, which are in a relative positions.

Comment: Please edit your question and write code here.

Comment: I edited the question, it was my first time that I added a codepen to my code so it took me a little bit to figure out how. Please don't downgrade me in the meantime

Answer (score 0):

add to a dropdown menu top "38px

```css
.dropdown-menu{
 top:38px !important;
 border: none !important;
 border-radius: 0 !important;
 color: black;
 /*display: block!important;*/
 /*box-shadow: 1px 1px 6px #767676;*/
}
```

Comment: It won't work, the only difference is that the position value on the main menu, I want to fix the sub dropdown menu.